# Deep nested routes and different components rendering, based on route path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I have deep nested routes in my routes.js file. As you can see in code bellow I have to render different component, based on route (if route is products I need to render Products.vue component, but if route goes deeper I need to render EmptyRouterView.vue component which contains template `<router-view></router-view>` so I can render sub route components).

```
{
    path: '/products',
    name: 'products',
    component: {
        render(c) {
            if (this.$route.name === 'products') {
                return c(require('pages/Products/Products.vue').default)
            } else {
                return c(require('components/EmptyRouterView.vue').default);
            }
        }
    },
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
        allowedPositions: '*'
    },
    children: [
        // Scan product to get info
        {
            path: '/products/search-product',
            name: 'search-product',
            component: () => import('pages/Products/SearchProduct.vue'),
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                allowedPositions:   '*'
            }
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

I wonder if there is some short or better way to do this? For example (I know I can't call this in arrow function) something like this?

```
component: () => {
    this.$route.name === 'products' ? require('pages/Products/Products.vue').default : require('components/EmptyRouterView.vue').default
}
```

Or do you see if there is possible to do this some completely other way?

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can i.e. create another `.vue`-file and include both components inside (`<cmp-1 />` & `<cmp2 />`). Then you can build your `if`-statement inside the template with another `template`-tag:

```
<template v-if="boolean">
<cmp-1 />
</template>
<template v-else>
<cmp-2 />
</template>
```

The if depends on your route then.

Comment: Nice! Don't know why didn't I think of that! Maybe it was to early! ;) Thank you